# Powershell to select columns from csv when condition matches

Tags: powershell-3.0

My csv looks like this

```
SvnDirectory    Release
export          Yes
import
service         Yes
```

My script should select only those SvnDirectory names whole Release value is "Yes" and store in an array.

Script

```
$svnDirectory = import-csv  training.csv | % {$_.SvnDirectory -and $_.Release -eq "Yes"}
Write-host $svnDirectory
```

Without the and condition the script works fine. It selects all the svndirectory names and stores in array. But when I give the condition, it returns True false true instead of the svndirectory filed value.  Can someone please let me know what I am missing here. I am new to powershell.

```
My expected output is $svnDirectory = export   service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

```
   $file = import-csv training.csv
   $svnDirectory = $file | Where-Object{$_.Release -eq "Yes"} | %  {$_.SvnDirectory} 
   Write-host $svnDirectory
```